# Server Aliases on NGINX

Tags: nginx, alias, serveralias

I'm moving a site to a new server running on NGINX.  The old site's Apache2 VirtualHost has `ServerAlias` configured that I want to replicate in the NGINX configuration.

From what [I've read on the NGINX Docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) this seems to be simply achieved with `server_name`.

I just want to make sure what I have is correct.

**From APACHE2**

```
ServerAlias our-domain.com www1.our-domain.com our-domain.ie
```

**To NGINX**

```
server_name www.our-domain.com our-domain.com www.our-domain.ie our-domain.ie;
```

Answer (score 84):

Yes, just using `server_name` with serveral names is perfectly correct.  The first name will be used as canonical one (similar to Apache `ServerName`), and others as aliases (similar to Apache `ServerAlias`).